# Cleaner way to write this MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I generate below query through php

```
$sql .= "Select * from test";

$sub_sql = '';

foreach($value as $n_k => $n_v)
{
    switch($n_v)
    {
        case '1':
            $sub_sql .= " OR (id = 1 )"; 
        break;
        case '2':
            $sub_sql .= " OR (category = 4) ";
        break;
        case '3':
            $sub_sql .= " OR (location = 'U.S.') ";
        break;  
    }
}

if($sub_sql != '')
{
    $sql .= " where ( 0 ".$sub_sql." ) ";
}

$sql .= "GROUP BY id  ORDER BY stored_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ";
```

But as you'll can see where `$subsql` is concatenated to `$sql`, that part looks really messy. Evn though it works fine but it looks really poor. Can anyone pls help me with this?

Comment: For example I think it would help to remove double whitespaces, and spell mysql keywords capitalized. Furthermore this seems to be off-topic because you don't really have a question about coding, but there's the SE Codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com site, try it there.

Comment: @wumm First of all thanks for you comment. secondly I really don't mind having the whitespaces and the capitalization as it is not really going to affect the result. Also I very well understand that I can use SE Codereview for this but already saw some of the similar question so thought I also could give it a try as I am desperately in need to get the answer as I can't really think of any other solution + my project leader wont allow such queries also. Thanx again.

Comment: If the goal is to get rid of the dynamic sql, you will need to parameterize the query, see this question to guide you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: So what is REALLY the problem here?  Your project leader doesn't like your code formatting?  Well why don't you agree on a coding style guide? Sometimes you have the need to build queries dynamically like this.  I don't really see the problem here other than I would agree with comment by @wumm that your are stylistically inconsistent. Maybe something different could be done with your loop/switch construct, but it's hard to say without understanding what is in `$value`.

Comment: @MikeBrant problem here is that as you can see where I concatenate both the queries it is something like `WHERE (0 OR $n_v = 2 AND category = 4)` I think which is not correct as I add `0` to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a simplified example? Because I see no reason not to simplify it like this:

```
$sql .= "Select * from test where a=1";

foreach($value as $n_k => $n_v)
{
    switch($n_v)
    {
        case '1':
            $sql .= " AND (id = 1 )"; 
        break;
        case '2':
            $sql .= " AND (category = 4)";
        break;
        case '3':
            $sql .= " AND (location = 'U.S.')";
        break;  
    }
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY stored_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ";
```

Note, that I removed the `GROUP BY` from your statement. You shouldn't use it, if you don't use aggregate functions. Group by collapses group of rows and displays random rows from each group. If you have a need to remove duplicate rows, consider to use the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `SELECT` clause.

**UPDATE:**

Your new version can be shortened like this:

```
$sql .= "Select * from test";

foreach($value as $n_k => $n_v)
{
    switch($n_v)
    {
        case '1':
            $sql .= " where (id = 1 ) "; 
        break;
        case '2':
            $sql .= " where (category = 4) ";
        break;
        case '3':
            $sql .= " where (location = 'U.S.') ";
        break;  
    }
}

$sql .= " GROUP BY id  ORDER BY stored_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ";
```

Basically it comes down to this. If you have to add **multiple** `AND` conditions, you always add a `WHERE 1=1` (if you have no other fix (non-dynamic) conditions) to the query. It doesn't change anything, the optimizer will throw it away again. But you can easily append as many conditions as you want. That's what I did in my original answer before your edit. Note though, that you can not just append `OR whatever = true` when you are mixing `AND` and `OR` conditions. You will have to use parantheses to not get a false resultset. This is where your `(0 OR ...)` thing comes from. Since you only have 1 condition, there's no need at all for all I said right now. Just add it as `WHERE whatever = true` and that's it.

Comment: GROUP BY's not really doing it for me.

Comment: @fancyPants I'll surely keep in mind next time about the group by's. thanks. I have updated the question, Sorry my bad.

Comment: @fancyPants but I dont think it will work because if more than one condition is satisfied then it will keep on appending `where` as it goes in a loop and I will end up getting sql errors

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the conditions to the sql?

Something like:

```
Select * from test where a=1
AND 
(
  ($n_v = 1 AND id = 1)
  OR
  ($n_v = 2 AND category = 4)
  OR
  ($n_v = 3 AND location = 'U.S.')
)
```